# Printing out each increment of variable

Tags: java

I have a service that allows a user to "toast" bread.

It's below

```
public void Toasting(){
        if(breadLevel >= 0){
            while(temp < 5){
                toasting = true;
                temp++;
            }

        } else {
            toasting = false;
        }
        System.out.println(breadLevel);
    }
```

So if their is bread is the toaster, and while the temp is less then 5, toasting is happening, and increment the temp by one.

How would Increase the temp variable by 1 every 2 seconds.

Also I want to send a status update to the user. So each time the temp is incremented the user is notified.

```
@Override
    public String getStatus() {
        String message = "";

        if(toasting = true){
            message = "The current temp is" +temp;
        }

        return message;
    }
```

This get status method only prints when the temp reaches 5. Instead of incremently informing the user.

Comment: `if (toasting == true)` or `if (toasting)`

Comment: It's completely unclear what specifically do you mean. These methods say nothing in relation to what you want, because "I want to notify user" has a whole lot of stuff missing to even begin to answer about how can one do it.

Answer (score 1):

To wait 2 seconds in Java use

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

For example:

```
if(breadLevel >= 0){
    while(temp < 5){
        toasting = true;
        temp++;
        System.out.println(getStatus())
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
    toasting = false; //no longer toasting so set to false
}
```

Comment: do System.out.println(getStatus()) so you're using OP's method

Comment: what variable should be changed once the bread is done being toasted?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, didn't you write the original code? There is nothing about finishing anything in your original question.

Comment: I didn't write the question @M.Prokhorov

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, ah, Ok. My bad.